# bootstrap not working accordingly

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have viewed one tutorial online about creating a responsive navigation bar which is suppose to look like this

[image]
[image]

I have followed accordingly, added the css file along with the js file but it isn't working. It ends up like this. The GUI is actually working fine. However, there isn't any extension to show the other two option i have like the picture above. Nothing happens when i click the extension.

[image]

This is how i enter my codes for the responsive navbar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>iPolice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" >
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>



<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src ="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta2)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->    
</head>

<body>

<div class="nav bar navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="navbar-inner">
           <div class ="container">
               <a class ="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                   <span class="icon-th-list"></span>
               </a>
               <a href="#" class="brand">Your Logo</a>

               <div class="nav-collapse colapse">

                   <ul class="nav pull-right">
                       <li class="active"><a href="#">Entry01</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Entry02</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>    
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">  </script>

    <div id="ContentPlaceHolder">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

</form>

    </body>
```

I'm pretty sure i have added my css and javascript file in the correct position.

I'm trying to allow my navbar ( picture below ) to appear nicely under the responsive design when the width is being reduced.

[image]

I have also downloaded the bootstrap from this [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)

Any help and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S: As shown in the picture below, i already have my own darkgrey navigation bar in my webapp. I'm wondering is it possible to intergrate both the twitterbootstrap and my existing navbar together?

***UPDATE***

Sorry. My initial post has left out something important such as the link between my asp masterpage in visual studio2012 with my CSS. However, despite adding the necessary css, the extension in the bootstrap isn't function well.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the doctype and the bootstrap.css is not linked.
You should have a look on the bootstrap web site. (see the following link)
[Basic template for bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#html-template)

---

You should try something like : [My code](http://pastebin.com/vmwPx1Jt) (I can't paste it here, an error occurs).

---

Have a look to [Bootstrap - Component](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar)

Comment: Sorry. i have left out something important which is thelink between my master and the CSS file which i have updated on my question above. However, after adding the css, the gui is working fine but not the extension. Nothing happened when i clicked the extension

Comment: I can see there is a lot of references to jquery. Is that normal ?This can be a problem. Did you add the doctype ?

Comment: yes i have added this <!DOCTYPE html>. If i have not mistaken it's a default tag whenever you try to create a html webpage. As for the various reference, some of them are to enable the functionality of my slideshow header which i believe it shouldn't affect the others as from my point of view each works individually.

Comment: For me there's some problems in the script inclusion.
The first line include jQuery **1.4**, 
The 4th include one 2nd time jquery (v?.??)
The last include **1.9** and re-include jquery 

Multiples inclusion can cause some troubles.Try to remove some then to add your lines one by one

Comment: The weird part is when i remove all my script inclusion there isn't any error prompt. But nevertheless, i tried removing each and tried running differently but it's still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

The CSS doesn't load; it can be proved by opening Developer Console > Network.

remove the tags surrounding your `style.css`.

Comment: The "comment" tag around the style.css was the css of my old navbar. Currently, i'm just testing out the sample twitterbootstrap given by a tutorial online. So "uncommenting" the stlye.css wont make a difference.

Comment: but you haven't included other CSS, therefore your page is rendered without CSS. Also, syntax of commenting codes is incorrect

Comment: Sorry. i have left out something important which is thelink between my masterpage and the CSS file which i have updated on my question above. However, after adding the css, the gui is working fine but not the extension. Nothing happened when i clicked the extension
As for the commenting codes, there was a comment function in VS2012. I just followed accordingly. Regards.